# I have a table of entries. I want to select only records that have an entry for every month in the last 12 months.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table from which I want to select only records that have an entry for every month in the last 12 months from a rolling date. The format of the table is: Record#, Date, LocationName.

I know I can do a sub-query to get everything with dates between a start and end date. However, I need to ensure that the record has an entry for each of those months as opposed to just retrieving values if they fall between them.

I started off with

```
select Record#, Date from Table where datediff(mm,Date,getdate()) < 12 order by Record#
```

For a rolling date, I switched to:

```
select Record#, Date from Table where Date between start_date and end_date order by Record#
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `exists()` with an aggregation query using the `having` clause with `count(distinct ...)` to make sure that 12 months of records exist for a given `Record#`

```
select 
    t.[Record#]
  , t.Date 
from tbl t 
where t.Date >= @start_date
  and t.Date <= @end_date 
  and exists (
  select 1
  from tbl i
  where i.[Record#] = t.[Record#]
    and i.Date >= @start_date
    and i.Date <= @end_date
  group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, i.Date), 0)
  having count(distinct dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, i.Date), 0)) = 12
  )
order by [Record#]
```

Date range query reference:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. This worked perfectly!